# How to update Firebase in Xcode project?

Tags: ios, firebase, admob, cocoapods, xcode8

I'm trying to update Firebase from 7.10 to 7.11. It is required if you want to publish an app that is running AdMob in Xcode 8. How do I update the Firebase software in my app?

I'm using cocoa pods. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Simply run `pod update` on your terminal to update all pods.

Comment: @FabIan welcome..Glad could help..Accept it as the answer please since it worked for you :)

Comment: Thanks!! +1 for you @eshirima

Comment: @FabIan Please accept as answer since it resolved your issue and for the question to be closed on SO